No puedo pasar el proxy consumiendo un WSDL
Estoy intentando pasar el proxy para consumir un servicio WSDL pero cuando ejecuto el código, me devuelve el error
El objeto de comunicación, System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[EnvioAsistenciasRGA.WRRGA.IEmpresasPublicService], no se puede usar para la comunicación porque se encuentra en el estado Faulted.

Si quito la autenticación del proxy, el código funciona correctamente.
private (bool, string, string) SendRequest(WRRGA.CrearOcurrenciaAperturaRequest apertura, WRRGA.CrearOcurrenciaRequest ocurrencia)
{
    try
    {

        
        WRRGA.EmpresasPublicServiceClient client = new WRRGA.EmpresasPublicServiceClient();      

        logger.Info("Cliente soap creado");

        // Configurar el proxy
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://mi.proxy.lan:8080", true);

        // Si el proxy requiere autenticación, proporciona las credenciales
        proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuarioproxy", "contraseñaproxy");

        // Asignar el proxy a la configuración global
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;

        WRRGA.CrearOcurrenciaAperturaResponse aperturaResponse = new WRRGA.CrearOcurrenciaAperturaResponse();
        WRRGA.CrearOcurrenciaResponse ocurrenciaResponse = new WRRGA.CrearOcurrenciaResponse();

        //System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

     

        using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
        //metemos la cabecera
        SoapAuthHeader.Create("Rga.Ceaph.Token", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        logger.Info("Header creado");

            if (apertura != null)
            {
                logger.Info("CrearOcurrenciaApertura");
                Console.WriteLine("CrearOcurrenciaApertura-PolizaSiniestro: " + apertura.PolizaSiniestro);
                aperturaResponse = client.CrearOcurrenciaApertura(apertura);                
                return (aperturaResponse.Exito, aperturaResponse.Exito == true ? "0" : "1", aperturaResponse.Exception != null ? aperturaResponse.Exception.Message : string.Empty);
            }
            else if (ocurrencia != null)
            {
                logger.Info("CrearOcurrencia");
                ocurrenciaResponse = client.CrearOcurrencia(ocurrencia);                
                return (ocurrenciaResponse.Exito, ocurrenciaResponse.Exito == true? "0" : "1", ocurrenciaResponse.Exception != null ? ocurrenciaResponse.Exception.Message : string.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                return (false, string.Empty, string.Empty);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (FaultException faultEx)
    {
        logger.Error($"FaultException: {faultEx.Message}");
        return (false, "0", "FaultException al enviar");
    }
    catch (CommunicationException commEx)
    {
        logger.Error($"CommunicationException: {commEx.Message}");
        return (false, "0", "CommunicationException al enviar");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(string.Format("Error en el método '{0}'. Mensaje: {1}", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message));
        return (false, "0", "Excepcion al enviar");
    }

Espero pasar el proxy y poder enviar el token sin problemas.
Gracias

Si configuras, por el ejemplo el SoapUI con el proxy en cuestión, ¿te dice lo mismo?
Huele a que el proxy está haciendo algo más de lo esperado.
